# Javascript - CasperJS using proxy causing "About:blank" url

Tags: javascript, proxy, casperjs

I've been trying to make my casperjs code to work using proxy these last few days.
When i try running the code without proxy, the code run as expected.

```
casperjs somefile.js arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But when i tried to run using --proxy option,

```
casperjs somefile.js --proxy=SOME_PROXY arg1 arg2 arg3
```

The console become error like these

```
CasperError: Cannot dispatch mousedown event on nonexistent selector: a
```

And when i tried to debug inside casper.start using this.getCurrentUrl(), i get:

```
"about:blank"
```

While my url is correct...
Here is a simpler version of my code

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

var utils   = require('utils'),
    url     = 'SOME URL';

casper.start(url, function() {
    utils.dump(this.getCurrentUrl());
    utils.dump(url);
});

casper.run();
```

Anybody have encountered the same issue and fixed the problem?

Comment: I neved saw a problem with proxies. Are you sure you have not credentials to use this proxy ? Can you try to display all HTML of the webpage to see if it is not the proxy page ?

Comment: i can't display the html   when about to capture, i got the error...  i've been looking around, some says it was phantomjs fault   i'll update it as soon as i've found the solution